# How to create a listview in android with 2 columns, each of them having items with different height?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am quite new to android, so I apologize in advance for any inconveniences my question may provoke.

I would like to create a listview that looks exactly like this image.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/42311831@N07/10145401953/

The listview would have 2 columns, each having custom views with variable height (represented on the image with rectangular shapes in different colors).

Creating this with 2 different listviews would be quite an easy job.

My approach would be creating 2 listviews and making them kind of "listen" to each-others on-scroll event, and responding to it by scrolling themselves simultaneously. That would mean, if I scroll down one of those 2 listviews, the other one would respond as if I had scrolled it down as well.

I am not sure that this is the right solution, so I would like to ask if anyone has experience with creating a component like this one?

Thank you very much for your time,
Bojan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thaats not a listview its a gridview. a gridview that could be adjusted as per the content in each grids, you can create a simple gridview with fixed size in a same way a you create a linear layout, that is

```
define a gridview xml
define gridview row xml (this contains textviews, edittext, buttons etc) or from your image it can have colors like red,green,blue etc
```

> you  can set number of gridview as 1 while portrait mode and 2 while landscape mode to get what your image is looking

create above xml and in your activity you can inflate it just the way listviews are inflated.

> or incase you need grids with uneven sizes check this library

http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/pinterest-like-adapterview/

i hope im clear and you appreciate my effort :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Maulik, it was extremely helpful.
I appreciate it a lot!!! :)